# Determining physical memory address of an application running in Android

Tags: android, memory-management, swap

I want to test out mlock() command on an application. How do I determine the physical memory addresses of applications currently running in an Android device?

Answer (score 1):

[mlock()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mlock.html) is a system call that operates on the address space of the current process.  It doesn't affect other processes.

This is a privileged operation, which means apps can't use it unless you have a rooted device and have modified system_server to enable the appropriate capability.

Android devices don't swap dirty pages out of RAM, and actively kill off background processes when the system gets low on memory, so `mlock()` is less useful on Android that it might be in other contexts.

Comment: There are applications which enables swap although it does not give any significant performance increase. I would like to run some tests with mlock() if it is possible. 

http://code.google.com/p/a-swapper/. This application enables it and it uses swapon() and swapoff(), is mlock() possible here?